# SSIS transformation : 46 columns into 4

Tags: excel, ssis

I have a business intelligence SSIS project, and I'm preparing my fact table, the problem in here, is that my source is an excel file with 46 columns and my fact table needs only 4, but I need the information from the 46 columns.

I will try to simplify with a little example:

Source:

```
code_agency | date     | OC_realisation | CV_realistion | NTC_realisation
700         | 1/1/2014 |      4         |     6         |      3
200         | 1/1/2014 |      5         |     1         |      0
```

Destination

```
code_agency | date     | Code_realisation | value 
700         | 1/1/2014 |      OC          |    4       
700         | 1/1/2014 |      CC          |    6        
700         | 1/1/2014 |      NTC         |    3     
200         | 1/1/2014 |      OC          |    5
200         | 1/1/2014 |      CC          |    1
200         | 1/1/2014 |      NTC         |    0
```

This was an example with only 3 realization columns, but I really have 46 on my excel source.
Does anyone know how to achieve the desired output? Please help and thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 1. Use **Unpivot** transformation.

**[Unpivot Transformation Example](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1761/how-to-use-the-unpivot-data-flow-transform-in-sql-server-integration-services-ssis/)**

Option 2: Handle it in TSQL

```
SELECT Code_Agency, date, 'OC' AS Code_realisation, OC_realisation AS value
UNION ALL
SELECT Code_Agency, date, 'CC' AS Code_realisation, CC_realisation AS value
UNION ALL
SELECT Code_Agency, date, 'NTC' AS Code_realisation, NTC_realisation AS value
.
.
.
.
```